# Why did Cecilia remove the leash on the dog?

Tags: the-invisible-man-2020

In the opening scene of *The Invisible Man*, Cecilia escapes from home and removes the leash on the dog. Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the opening sequence, Cecilia escapes the house. Once outside, she hears her dog groaning, behind her, motionless. She then goes to the dog.

Close-up on the leash that shows "invisible fence" (electrical device). Cecilia says

> I can't take you with me

and removes the leash. The dog is free to go, as she won't be around to take care of it.